# Why does job.running in QISKit output False, even if the job is still running?

Tags: programming, qiskit

I submitted a job in the 0.5.0 version of QISKit using

```
job = execute(qc, 'ibmqx5', shots=shots)
```

This just submits the job, and does not wait for a result.

I then immediately tested whether the job was still running using

```
print(job.running)
```

This gave the result `False`. However, when I requested the result using

```
job.result()
```

This still took a while to get the result, suggesting that the job actually was still running after all. What is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three stages that the job goes through, as you'll see if you also print the status using `print(job.status)`.

The first is an initialization stage. This returns `False` for `job.running`, because it hasn't started running yet.

Then your job actually will run, and so give `True` for `job.running`. Finally it will have finished running, and so `job.running` goes back to `False`.

So don't use `job.running` to test whether a result is ready.